# Defining functions to filter and extract pandas data and plotting data on geopandas plots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I have been exploring various COVID-19 datasets and doing analysis.  Below is a 'cleaned' up version of my code.  I've been running in google's Colab, but should work on any machine with the modules available (tested).

Questions upfront:

1. How do I create a function of my technique to extract the data as I do below for each country or US state? My technique is denoted below with **My technique**
2. How do I plot (bubble plot) the data on the geopandas maps? I would like to create a new map for each date.  Then create a movie, but I haven't got that far.

Import modules

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
#%matplotlib inline
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from IPython import display
from ipywidgets import interact, widgets
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#from google.colab import files
```

Some setup parameters

```
chartcol='red'
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 5]
```

I am using the Johns Hopkins University Center for Systems Science and Engineering (JHU CSSE) dataset that is updated nightly (daily?).

```
# Get the data 
#Read Data for Cases, Deaths and Recoveries

ConfirmedCases_raw=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv')
Deaths_raw=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Deaths.csv')
Recoveries_raw=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_19-covid-Recovered.csv')
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 5]
```

Here I am creating a list of date strings that match the timeseries data column names.
The list ends 'yesterday' because the dataset isn't updated for 'today'.

```
#This produces a list of strings that matches the column names in the COVID-10 time series.
# Will use it to extract data to build country and state data later.

today = datetime.now()
today2=date.today()
yesterday = today2 - timedelta(days = 1)
covid_epoch=date(2020, 1, 22) 


delta = yesterday - covid_epoch
timeline=[]
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    #day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    day = covid_epoch + timedelta(days=i)
    timeline.append(day.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y"))
```

Now I use my 'technique' to extract the timeseries data in a way I can use it.  I would like to be able to do this with a function.

```
#Extracts data from csv file into time column and value column
#Creates a list of values from each time column
#Consider using melt to do this. How?
#Create a function to do this. How?
```

**My technique:** The block below is what I want to turn into a function

```
time = [];value = [];country=[];province= []
col_value = list(ConfirmedCases_raw.columns)
for i in timeline:
    time.append(i)
    value.append(ConfirmedCases_raw[i].sum())
```

Create a dataframe for all cases around the world. I fill the dataframe with sum values for all countries for the 'world' dataframe, 'time' and 'value'.

```
world = pd.DataFrame({'Timeline':time,'Covid-19 impact':value})

#Plot the world data

plt.plot(world['Timeline'],world['Covid-19 impact'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45);

plt.suptitle('World COVID-19 Confirmed Cases', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18);
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=16);
plt.grid(color='b', ls = '-.', lw = 0.25)
```

[image]

Again, do this to create a US dataframe. Filtered Confirmed cases for the United States

```
us_confirmed_raw=ConfirmedCases_raw[ConfirmedCases_raw['Country/Region']=='US']
```

Here is my data extraction block again:

```
time = [];value = [];country=[];province= []
col_value = list(us_confirmed_raw.columns)
for i in timeline:
    time.append(i)
    value.append(us_confirmed[i].sum())
```

And create dataframe and plot US data

```
us_confirmed = pd.DataFrame({'Timeline':time,'Covid-19 impact':value})
plt.plot(us_confirmed['Timeline'],us_confirmed['Covid-19 impact'])
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
plt.suptitle('USA COVID-19 Confirmed Cases', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18);
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=16);
plt.grid(color='r', ls = '-.', lw = 0.55)
```

[image]

And again for New Mexico.

```
nm_confirmed=us_confirmed_raw[us_confirmed_raw['Province/State']=='New Mexico']

time = [];value = [];country=[];province= []
col_value = list(nm_confirmed.columns)
for i in timeline:
    time.append(i)
    value.append(nm_confirmed[i].sum())

nm = pd.DataFrame({'Timeline':time,'Covid-19 impact':value})
plt.plot(nm['Timeline'],nm['Covid-19 impact'],linestyle='--', marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
plt.suptitle('New Mexico COVID-19 Confirmed Cases', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18);
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=16);
plt.grid(color='r', ls = '-.', lw = 0.25)
```

your right, maybe too many examples.

My next issue is creating maps.  Below I am using geopandas to create a map and plot data.

```
!pip install geopandas;
import geopandas
```

put the New Mexico data into a geopandas dataframe:

```
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    nm_confirmed, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(nm_confirmed.Long, nm_confirmed.Lat))
```

and plot the location of New Mexico.  I cannot figure out how to plot the COVID-19 data on this map.

```
# Creates a map of the world
# Show the location of new mexico

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

ax = world[world.continent == 'North America'].plot(
    color='white', edgecolor='black')

gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for question 1:

This function, 'get_state' returns the state data in the datafiles (US filtered):

```
def get_state(state):
  state_confirmed=us_confirmed_raw[us_confirmed_raw['Province/State']==state]
  col_value = list(state_confirmed.columns)
  time = [];value = [];
      for i in timeline:
        time.append(i)
        value.append(state_confirmed[i].sum())
  us_state = pd.DataFrame({'Timeline':time,'Covid-19 impact':value})
  return us_state
```

and it can be used directly,

```
state='Texas'
plt.plot(get_state(state).Timeline,get_state(state)['Covid-19 impact'],linestyle='--', marker='o')
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
plt.suptitle(state+' COVID-19 Confirmed Cases', fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18);
plt.ylabel('Count', fontsize=16);
plt.grid(color='r', ls = '-.', lw = 0.25)
```

which produces this plot,

[image]